# Application not comparing login data on MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, authentication, passwords

I created a login frame where the user has to enter a username or password. The user credentials are stored in an encrypted format (AES) on a MySQL database. For test purposes when the access button is pressed the frame takes the data entered in the `txtUsername` and `txtPassword`, encrypts them and sets the encrypted credentials in the `txtEncUName` and `txtEncPword`. The application will then compare the encrypted credentials with the encrypted data in the `txtEncUName` and `txtEncPword` textfields.

If the credentials are correct the user is granted access and directed to the respective page depending on if they have admin access or not. If their account has been locked, then they will be notified by a jLabel and access will not be granted. When I tested this earlier, it worked perfectly fine but now here's my problem:

When I try login, the application immediately says that the account is inaccessible. I have checked the credentials and they are correct. No errors come up and the stack trace doesn't come up either.

What can I do to get this to check the credentials properly?

Here is the method used for the access button:

```
public void loginMethod()
{
String user = txtUsername.getText();
        String pwd = new String(txtPassword.getPassword());

        try
        {
            String enc1 = LoginFrame.encrypt(user);
            String enc2 = LoginFrame.encrypt(pwd);

            encUname.setText(enc1);
            encPword.setText(enc2);

            String aes1 = encUname.getText();
            String aes2 = encPword.getText();

            String getAccess = "select * from login_db";            

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_db","root","password");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(getAccess);

            if(rs.next())
            {
                String username = rs.getString("emp_num");
                String password = rs.getString("pword");
                String access = rs.getString("adminAccess");
                String locked = rs.getString("accLocked");

                if((aes1.equals(username)) && (aes2.equals(password)) && (access.equals("Yes"))&& ("No".equals(locked)))
                {
                    AdminPage ap = new AdminPage();
                    ap.setVisible(true);
                    this.dispose();
                }

                else if ((aes1.equals(username)) && (aes2.equals(password)) && (access.equals("No"))&& ("No".equals(locked)))
                {
                    EmployeeMainPage emp = new EmployeeMainPage();
                    emp.setVisible(true);
                    this.dispose();
                }

                else if((aes1.equals(username)) && (aes2.equals(password)) && (access.equals("Yes"))&& ("Yes".equals(locked)))
                {
                    lblWrongLogin.setVisible(true);
                    lblWrongLogin.setText("Account inaccesible, please contact admin for support.");
                }
                else if((locked.equals("Yes")))
                {
                    lblWrongLogin.setVisible(true);
                    lblWrongLogin.setText("Account inaccessible, please contact admin for support.");
                }
        }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: I know you're suppose to use hashing for passwords and I am planning on hashing the passwords when the application is closer to completion. I just used AES for now as a test as I'm still learning data security :). But thanks for the link, I will definitely look over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String getAccess = "select * from login_db";
```

The query above selects all rows from the database, but the code...

```
if(rs.next())
```

...only checks if the first row matches - there will be issues if there is more than a single row. Consider changing the query to look for matches to username and password

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( "select * from login_db where emp_num=? AND pword=?");
ps.setString(1, aes1);
ps.setString(2, aes2); 
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if ( rs.next() ){
    //logic here
}
```